# OpenZeppelin and chainlink not found; the error is probably on the dependencies; The npm I also not working

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, openzeppelin, brownie

Lottery.sol file
"
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

"contracts/Lottery.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
^--------------------------------------------------------------------------^

contracts/Lottery.sol:5:1: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
^--------------------------------------------------^"

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
    
    import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
    
    contract Lottery is Ownable {
        address payable[] public players;
        uint256 public usdEntryFee;
        AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;
        enum LOTTERY_STATE {
            OPEN,
            CLOSED,
            CALCULATING_WINNER
        }
        LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;
        // OPEN = 0
        //CLOSED = 1
        //CALCULATING_WINNER = 2
    
        LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;
    
        constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
            usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
            ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
            lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED; // or "lottery_state = 1;
        }
    
        function enter() public {
            // $50 minimum
            require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN); // or lottery_state == 0;
            require(msg.sender >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enough ETH!");
            players.push(msg.sender);
        }
    
        function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
            (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
            uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**10; //18 decimals
            //50, 2000 / ETH
            // 50/2,000
            //50 * 100000 / 2000
            uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
            return costToEnter;
        }
    
        function startLottery() public onlyOwner {
            require(
                lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED,
                "Can't start a new lottery yet!"
            );
            lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
        }
    
        function endLottery() public {
            //require(lottery_state == 50.000, "The winner is 50.000");
            //lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
        }
    }
```

brownie-config.yaml file

```
dependecies: 
  - smartcontractgit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0 // the error is probably here
compile:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0' // The error can be here
       
networks: 
   mainnet-fork: 
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `.yaml`.

The dependencies don't match the remappings. The following should work.

```
dependecies: 
  -  smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1 //error was here
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0 
compiler: // The error was also here
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
```

After this you will get a few errors on your contract logic but the dependencies will be fixed.

In your contract you declare twice the variable `auction_state`, delete one of them. Also, the `enter()` function must be `payable public` since it recives eth. You should change `msg.sender` for `msg.value`. Those changes will get your contract compiled. I'll copy the compilable contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
    
    import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
    
    contract Lottery is Ownable {
        address payable[] public players;
        uint256 public usdEntryFee;
        AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;

        enum LOTTERY_STATE {
            OPEN,
            CLOSED,
            CALCULATING_WINNER
        }

        // OPEN = 0
        //CLOSED = 1
        //CALCULATING_WINNER = 2
    
        LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;
    
        constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
            usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
            ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
            lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED; // or "lottery_state = 1;
        }
    
        function enter() payable public {
            // $50 minimum
            require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN); // or lottery_state == 0;
            require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enough ETH!");
            players.push(msg.sender);
        }
    
        function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
            (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
            uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**10; //18 decimals
            //50, 2000 / ETH
            // 50/2,000
            //50 * 100000 / 2000
            uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
            return costToEnter;
        }
    
        function startLottery() public onlyOwner {
            require(
                lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED,
                "Can't start a new lottery yet!"
            );
            lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
        }
    
        function endLottery() public {
            //require(lottery_state == 50.000, "The winner is 50.000");
            //lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
        }
    }
```